# Drop a column in a nested structure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following schema.

```
|--items : array
   |-- element : struct
       |-- id : long
       |-- value : double        
       |-- stock : array
           |-- element : string
```

I’m trying to drop stock column from my schema, my desired output is:

```
|--items : array
   |-- element : struct
       |-- id : long
       |-- value : double
```

I’ve tried to drop the column using the following codes:

```
df = df.withColumn(‘items’, F.col(‘items’).dropFields(‘stock’)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Parameter 1 requires “STRUCT” type, however “items” has type “Array<Struct…”
```

I also tried

```
df = df.withColumn(“items”, F.col(“items”).cast(cast)
```

Note: My `cast` here is a schema without the stock, but I got the following error:

```
Cannot resolve “items” due to data type mismatch: cannot cast “source schema…” to “desired schema…”
```

So, my doubt is, how can I drop the stock column to get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`dropFields`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.dropFields.html) requires a column of struct type** but in your case you have column  which contains array of structs. The solution is to apply a `transform` function on each struct inside array and drop the corresponding field

```
df = df.withColumn('items', F.transform('items', lambda x: x.dropFields('stock')))
```

---

```
root
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help? I’ve posted another question regarding nested structures, if you want to check this out, it’s [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77375859/apply-lambda-function-in-a-nested-field-spark)

Comment: I have added the answer.