# Apply lambda function in a nested field Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following schema:

```
--items : array
   |-- element : struct
       |-- id : long
       |-- value : double        
       |-- stock : struct
           |-- centerList : array
               |-- element : struct
                   |-- center : struct
```

I can iterate over items using

```
df = df.withColumn(‘items’, F.transform(‘items’, lambda x : x.dropFields(‘value’)
```

But how can I iterate over centerList? I’ve tried:

```
df = df.withColumn(‘items’, F.transform(‘items’, lambda x : x.withField(‘stock.centerList’, F.transform(‘centerList’, lambda y: y.drop(‘center’)))
```

But when I run my code I got the following error:

```
[UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column, variable, or function parameter with name ‘centerList’ cannot be resolved.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is correct but you need to properly reference the `centerList` column of the current stock in the inner transformation operation

```
def transform(col):
    return F.transform(
        col,
        lambda x: x.withField(
            'stock.centerList',
            F.transform(
                x['stock']['centerList'], 
                lambda y: y.dropFields('center')
            )
        )
    )

df = df.withColumn('items', transform('items'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just missing a prefix here, should be:

```
F.transform(‘stock.centerList’, lambda y: y.drop(‘center’))
             ^^^^^^
```

Comment: When I run your code I got the following error `’Column’ object is not callable`. I tried to do `df = df.withColumn(‘items’, F.transform(‘items’, lambda x : x.withField(‘stock.centerList’, F.transform(‘stock.centerList’, lambda y: y.dropFields(‘center’)))` but  I got the same error of the question  `[UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column, variable, or function parameter with name ‘stock’.‘centerList’ cannot be resolved.`